# How to reset a password of iWiki

Tags: sql-update, mediawiki, wiki

Have a local copy of Wiki (MediaWiki) but my predecessor left without handing over the password.
I got access to the server panel, and to mySQL, but despite I try to change the password as explained at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Resetting_passwords I can't get it working.

In the localSetting.php file there is not a salt specified, which from ver 1.13 onward seems to be deprecated, but somehow my password have one.

E.g. :B:d1c1ee33:115272fdacb0ff5f6dcb3639d0bc08b3

Looking at the ./includes/User.php file, there is a crypt function that generate a random salt, so technically as long as I use a random name while using the following update statement I should be fine.

```
UPDATE `user` SET user_password = CONCAT(':B:somesalt:', MD5(CONCAT('somesalt-', MD5('somepass')))) WHERE user_name = 'someuser';
```

That's not the case. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

Use a maintenance script such as `changePassword.php` or [`createAndPromote.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CreateAndPromote.php).